# Unable to locate element while opening a new tab in chrome v 81

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

While running automation python script I am unable to locate element in a new tab. In the first tab I am able to login into the application then script tries to open a new tab which is happening properly but it is unable to locate any element eg.
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/register.php' and text()='Register']"}

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class loginphp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://phptravels.com/")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.driver.maximize_window()


    def test_login(self):
        driver = self.driver        
        parentguid=driver.current_window_handle
        login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='login log']").click()
        allGUID=driver.window_handles
        for guid in allGUID:
            if allGUID!=parentguid:
                drop = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/register.php' and text()='Register']").click()            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

HTML-This is the html tag of the element that i want to  locate

```
<a href="/register.php">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with your xpath expression; try changing it from

```
//a[@href='/register.php' and text()='Register']
```

to

```
//a[@href='/register.php'][text()='Register']
```

and see if that works.

If not, please edit your question and post the html snippet you are trying to select.

Comment: Changed the xpath its not working.The problem is its not locating any element from the child screen.whereas the same xpath is working absolutely fine individually

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

//a[contains(@href,'register.php') and contains(text(),'Register')]